# Forklift Tools syntax

Tags: bash, script

In Forklift there is an [Tools option](https://binarynights.com/manual#ptools), which allows to make quick actions.

But I don't really get how to create one. For example a simple one - to copy files from one pane to another.

```
cp $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES $TARGET_PATH
/bin/bash cp $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES $TARGET_PATH
/bin/bash/cp $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES $TARGET_PATH
```

I tried these three variants but none of them work.

Error messages:

1. "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"
2. "/bin/cp: /bin/cp: cannot execute binary file"
3. "The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory".

I need some other stuff like this - to covert .rtf files to .odt with a bash command:

```
soffice --convert-to odt $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES
```

What should i write? Maybe /bin/bash in the beginning? Still doesn't work.

Comment: From looking at the documentation `/bin/cp $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES $TARGET_PATH` should work (the other two for sure won't work). Do you have two panes open and some files selected in the active one?

Comment: Also, are you sure your second error message was caused by any of the three things you've tried? Can you try `/bin/echo cp $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES xxx $TARGET_PATH > /tmp/fl.txt` and then add the content of `/tmp/fl.txt` to your question?

Comment: @nohillside The "/bin/cp" worked! Thanks. It appears that i didn't write the location of the command write. So i located the soffice command and "/usr/local/bin/soffice --convert-to odt $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES" worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the example in the documentation you need to specificy the full path to the commands you want to run

```
/bin/cp $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES $TARGET_PATH
/path/to/soffice --convert-to odt $SOURCE_SELECTION_NAMES
```